# Is there any way to configure the API_URL for web-app API calls at runtime or while deploying rather than at build time?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, webpack, ansible

I am using Webpack to bundle my React application.

In production, I am using a Dockerfile to serve the static files generated using `npm build` using Nginx.
Then this docker image is then deployed using Ansible.

Right now I have to specify the `API_URL` for the requests to the server at the build time using an Environment file OR use Webpack build-time settings.

But, I want to be able to specify this URL while deploying as I will only know the server URL then.

**What I have tried:**

- I can mount Docker volumes to change variables, but I want to avoid changing the minified code.
- I tried using a `config.json` file in assets, but on importing that file in my JS code, Webpack resolves and loads it inline as minified JS code and I cannot just replace the `config.json` file in assets.
- Fetching the `config.json` file at runtime from the public URL makes me wait before I can make any API calls and before that file is resolved, all API requests will be made to an `undefined` URL.
- Another approach I tried was to split chunks in Webpack and split the `config.json` file.
  The minified file which I can edit is as below:

  ```js
  !function(e){var t={};function r(n){if(t[n])return t[n].exports;var o=t[n]={i:n,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[n].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,r),o.l=!0,o.exports}r.m=e,r.c=t,r.d=function(e,t,n){r.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:n})},r.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},r.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=r(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var n=Object.create(null);if(r.r(n),Object.defineProperty(n,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var o in e)r.d(n,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return n},r.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return r.d(t,"a",t),t},r.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},r.p="/",r(r.s=164)}({164:function(e){e.exports=JSON.parse('{"apiBaseURL":"http://localhost:3000"}')}});
  ```

Is there a simpler approach to solving this, which I might be missing?

Here is my Dockerfile for reference:

```
## Build the app
FROM node:12-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --silent
COPY . /app

RUN npm run build

## Expose port and start the app using nginx
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Another option is server-side includes (SSI) - I put some examples [here](https://github.com/spa-configuration). Or load a `config.js` from `index.html`, like [this project does](https://github.com/pivotal/postfacto/tree/master/web/public). There's also full-blown service discovery via a gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I solved it by adding environment variables.

The trick is to inject a js script into the head tag.

```
    <script src="/config.js"></script>
```

You can serve this file `config.js`  with content:

```
window._env_ = {
    API_URL: "http://localhost:3000",
};
```

This way you expose the variable `_env_` to the JS window object and use that anywhere in code.

The following resource is extremely helpful:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/